# Is it possible that I request an EC2 instance but can't get fulfilled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

**Edit: This question is NOT to ask about "Spot Instances"; this question is to ask regular "On Demand Instance".** I think I need to clarify this, after reading comments below.

Basically, my question is about whether I should consider the risk that when I need to launch an EC2 instance, but that EC2 region has run out of capacity and can't fulfill my request.

I understand the chance for the above situation is extremely low, but I'd like to understand if AWS has any SLA to make sure that situation/risk won't happen.

Comment: Yes, that is always possibility, specially if you are looking for "Spot Instance", chances are VERY HIGH.

Comment: Got any evidence to back that up, @Nambari?  I've been using AWS since 2009, and never ran into a situation like that with spot instances, so "very high" is something I'd appreciate quantification on.

Comment: "No. Spot fleet requests allow you to place multiple Spot instance bids simultaneously, and are subject to the same availability and prices as a single Spot instance request. For example, if no resources are available at your Spot fleet request bid price, we may be unable to fulfill your request partially or in full." https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#spot-fleet   @Paul

Comment: Well this might be talking about "price & resource combination", if OP falls into this category, that is when VERY HIGH make sense.

Comment: Spot Instance is not the same thing as a Spot Fleet request, and nothing you've said backs up your initial assertion that the chances of *not* getting a new Spot Instance is very high.  Data, friend, provide data. Not supposition.

Comment: @Paul I never experienced too, that could be due to the combination I need. If you fall into the "combination" (another param into this combination would be REGION, to make this quick), you sure will. The only data I have (unless I am ready to spend time& money) is AWS FAQ link listed there. If AWS FAQ is wrong, I am wrong too. In general "Spot fleet" is not very different, it is just "multiple".

Comment: @Nambari my point is that there is no indication of probability in anything you posted.  It says "if X then Y".  Not "If X, which has a 60% chance of happening, then Y".  Your comments haven't done anything other than repeat the OPs question in different ways.  Yes, there are lots of variables which will determine availability, and yes it's possible that you might not get everything you want when you want it.  That does NOT mean there is a "VERY HIGH" chance like you said, however.

Comment: @Paul 1) I know my comment FULLY doesn't answer OP question, which is why I commented instead of posting as answer (my understanding is that is what comments are for) 2) Initially OP post was NOT specific to one type of instance (even now region is not specified, but OP specified dedicated instance, which is are supported in every region), I hope you are aware that some regions don't support certain types of instances. When question has limited details, I can suppose lot of things and combinations. Hope that make sense.

Comment: I never said you didn't answer his question, I said your comments were not constructive.  You start by making assertions you can't back up and then when I ask you to back them up you change your story to say you were seeking clarification.  As posted in my answer, the SLA is NOT different for EC2 based on region or instance type, so even if your goal had been to clarify those things it would not have helped frame his question better.

Comment: @Paul 1) As I commented my only backup is the FAQ I read, if I understood FAQ wrong I am happy to learn and correct (as long as you provide link says FAQ is wrong) and I have been clear on my assumptions, if those are wrong (which after latest edit are, my first comment is NOT applicable for this question). I didn't ask any clarification, I just commented based on my assertions, my first comment says "if" 2) Based on my understanding EC2 SLA is after you acquire the instance, not before you acquire, which is what OP looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are protective controls in place to make the unavailability of a particular type of instance in a particular availability zone at a particular time unlikely... but it's possible, and there is no assurance provided by AWS that a given type of EC2 instance will be available for launch, on-demand, at any particular time, in any particular Availability Zone **unless you purchased reserved instances of that type, specifically in that availability zone.**  In that case, there is supposed to always be sufficient hardware available so that you can have the number of paid reserved instances running, at minimum, including the ability to launch enough new instances to bring the total up to that minimum.

Reserved instances are commonly discussed in the context of their associated discount, but they have two purposes:

> Reserved Instances are not physical instances, but rather a billing discount applied to the use of On-Demand Instances in your account. These On-Demand Instances must match certain attributes in order to benefit from the billing discount.
>
> **When you purchase Reserved Instances in a specific Availability Zone, they provide a capacity reservation.** *[(emphasis added)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts-on-demand-reserved-instances.html)*

For example, if you purchased 4 reserved t2.2xlarge instances in us-east-2a, the assurance is that you will always be able to launch enough to bring the total running instances of that type in that zone to 4.  If you already have 4, there's not an assurance of being able to start more, but there is an assurance that if you stop them, you will be able to start them again.

Pricing models for reserved instances has changed over the years, such that reserved instances are generally billed at the same rate whether they're running or not, so you can look at it one of two ways:

If you need the capacity all the time, you're getting a substantial discount... or, if you don't need the capacity all the time, you're technically paying all the time for capacity that is largely unneeded, but you are still paying less than you'd pay for on-demand instances without reservations, and you can either leave it running or launch it when you need it.

Should you consider the risk that an entire region has widespread capacity issues?  You should *consider* it, but there are, historically speaking, other significant outage scenarios that are more likely... EBS and S3 have both had failures that impaired the ability to launch instances, even though the capacity was idle in EC2.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I've had API calls to create EC2 resources fail many times due to lack of available AWS resources. I most commonly see this when attempting to create a new EC2 instance with Dedicated Tenancy in a specific Availability Zone.

Comment: But this also only partially answers the OP's question.  You indicate that it's a risk that you can't launch in a specific AZ, but to be a true risk answer you have to include probability of occurrence and impact, otherwise it's just apocryphal.  As an example, how often does it fail when it doesn't matter (e.g. when you can just launch in a different AZ instead w/o impact)?  I'm not an AWS fanboy or anything, I agree they can fail, I'm just pointing out that to answer a question like "should I consider the risk" it's incomplete not to help quantify that risk.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**. It is possible your instance request cannot be fulfilled. On-Demand instance does not guarantee you an instance. In particular,`t2.small` instances are more likely to be not fulfilled based on my experience. It is possible, AWS has only limited number of `t2.small` instances.

How can you make sure it is always fulfilled?

[**Reserve the instances**](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/reserved-instances/) for you so that it is not given to anyone else. But there is a cost associated with it. You have pay for the instance irrespective of whether you use it not. I am talking in general terms. Reserved instance is a complex topic, but that is the route you should take if you want AWS to guarantee you an instance.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, your launch request can fail because there is no available capacity in the relevant Availability Zone. I would say that it's a rare occurrence, but certainly possible.

You can mitigate by using multiple zones in the same region, other regions, or by using [Reserved Instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/reserved-instances/).

Answer (score 0):

Today it happened in an AWS account that I manage. If I am not wrong it was the family r4, exactly an r4.xlarge instance (4 hours ago) in Virgina Region. I had to choose a different AZ. That is why AWS always recommends working with more than one AZ.

But for that reason, I started to use [Scheduled Reserved Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-scheduled-instances.html)

You always will have for a period of time a reserved capacity of a family type of instance(s).

Sure, it works if you have a defined schedule or workflow.

Hope it helps you.